# sorting text file by date column

Tags: sort

How to sort text file by date properly in sample below? The problem is that `sort -k1,1` does not really work and neither can i use the dot notation such as `sort -k1.6,1.9 -k1.4,1.4 -k1.1,1.2` because the form does not have a fixed length. I came up with this horror

```
awk '{split($1,a,".");print a[1],a[2],a[3],$2}' test.txt | sort -k3,3 -k2,2 -k1,1 | awk '{print  $1 "." $2 "." $3,$4}'
```

while it works, i don't like the complexity. Can this be simplified, ideally with just `sort`?

```
25.3.2020   26698
24.3.2020   22600
23.3.2020   19624
22.3.2020   17377
21.3.2020   15584
20.3.2020   13704
4.3.2020    407
3.3.2020    340
2.3.2020    262
1.3.2020    211
29.2.2020   200
28.2.2020   193
27.2.2020   170
26.2.2020   135
11.2.2020   74
10.2.2020   72
9.2.2020    64
8.2.2020    62
7.2.2020    62
6.2.2020    56
5.2.2020    53
2.2.2020    43
1.2.2020    38
31.1.2020   37
30.1.2020   34
28.1.2020   28
27.1.2020   20
```

Comment: test.txt contains like it: 22.3.2020   17377?

Comment: @d1553ct10n yes, the test.txt contains the data that are pasted above.

Comment: @guest Yes it does

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sort -n -t. -k3,3 -k2,2 -k1,1 test.txt
```

- `-n` sort numerically
- `-t .` use dot character as field separator